# AS3 Feathers extended Button class does not render

Tags: actionscript-3, button, user-interface, starling-framework

I'm trying to extend the Button class, in an AS3 Feathers app, using the AeonDesktopTheme.

If I have this class:

```
package com.syncbuildrun
{
    import feathers.controls.Button;

    public class superButton extends Button
    {
        public function superButton()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

And I instantiate it like this:

```
var uiNode:superButton = new superButton();
uiNode.label = "sB";

uiNode.y = 10 + (i*100);
uiNode.x = 400;
uiNode.width = 90;
uiNode.height = 90;
m_visualPanel.addChild(uiNode);
uiNode.validate();
```

All I see is the "sb" text on the screen (in the wrong theme font). However, if I change the variable class and the instantiation class to Button, it works perfectly. What am I missing in my derived class? Do I need to register it with the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to write an initializer for it. That's the weirdest thing that was done by Josh - each class has **specific** initializer. You just need to add your class in the initializer functions just after the `Button`, and I think it will all work out.

Why he did it you may ask? Because he likes it this way :) If you have some more problems with Feathers I would be happy to help as I spent few terrible months with it and I don't want anyone else to struggle :)

Comment: That worked, thanks.  PITA, though. Need to extend the theme, specify an initializer inside that class... Not how I would have architected it.

Comment: That's the thing I don't like in the **only one** UI components out there supported by Adobe - it's done by a single person that you have to argue with in his own forum, to end up having an "I like it this way, if you don't - make your own". Yes, sometimes just to do a simple thing you need a few classes with 10 methods overriden.. I'm glad it worked out. Good luck with the project! Btw if you do lists and have problems with updating data or building/updating your items - just contact me :D